# NoClassDefFoundError: GuiceServletContextListener when running GWT + GAE from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, guice

When trying to run my project as a WebApplication from Eclipse, I have the following error:

```
[WARN] failed com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@4b903fd{/,D:\Dev\Projects\The Five Orbs\trunk\target\fiveorbs-0.1}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/servlet/GuiceServletContextListener
[WARN] failed JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler@eb4d977: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/servlet/GuiceServletContextListener
[WARN] Error starting handlers
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/servlet/GuiceServletContextListener
```

The class can be found at compile time though (my custom GuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener and compiles properly).

The `guice-servlet-3.0.jar` library appears both in the project build path and in the classpath of my Web Application Run Configuration in Eclipse.

The *Arguments* panel of my Run Configuration has the following config:
in *Program arguments*:

```
-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl TheFiveOrbs.jsp -logLevel INFO -server com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher -port 8888 -codeServerPort 9997 -war "D:\Dev\Projects\The Five Orbs\trunk\target\fiveorbs-0.1" com.fiveorbs.TheFiveOrbs
```

in VM arguments:

```
-javaagent:D:\Dev\Programs\appengine-java-sdk\lib\agent\appengine-agent.jar -Xmx512m -Dappengine.sdk.root=D:\Dev\Programs\appengine-java-sdk
```

When I run mvn gae:run from the command prompt with Maven, everything is fine though - the server starts properly and no exception is shown.

I have been struggling with this issue for a couple of hours, and really cannot fathom why it occurs.

Thanks in advance for any hint you might be able to offer.

Sébastien

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`guice-servlet-3.0.jar` should *not* be in you launch configuration classpath, it should live in your `D:\Dev\Projects\The Five Orbs\trunk\target\fiveorbs-0.1\WEB-INF\lib` folder.

Comment: How do you accomplish that? I have `guice-servlet-3.0.jar` in my classpath as a Maven dependency, so it won't make it into `WEB-INF/lib` inside Eclipse; Only the GAE SDK dependencies do. I have my WAR directory set to `src/main/webapp` (in there, there is the `WEB-INF/`), and I don't want to run my app from Maven's `target/`, since that requires running `mvn package` first.

Comment: And yet, that's how Maven works! (until the gwt-maven-plugin is somehow _fixed_). Honestly, you only need to run `mvn package -Dgwt.compiler.skip` when you change your dependencies, which is really not that often. An alternative is to not use the embedded server and use `mvn appengine:devserver` (or `mvn jetty:run` or `mvn tomcat7:run` when you're not using GAE) along with running the GWT DevMode in`-noserver` mode.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you exactly did for the non-maven experts?

Comment: I only see guice-servlet in my pom.xml: <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
What to do?